# expect appends data to a file

Tags: bash, expect

I made script:

```
for server in ${servTab[*]}; do
echo $server >> /var/www/html/df.txt
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh $server df | grep /appl/ | awk '{print \\\$4}' | sed s/%// >> /var/www/html/df.txt
expect "password"
send "$pass\r"
expect "$ "
EOF
```

but after run I have error:

```
spawn ssh server-1-lin df | grep /appl/ | awk '{print $4}' | sed s/%// >> /var/www/html/df.txt
ksh: /var/www/html/df.txt: cannot create [No such file or directory]
```

It works only if it looks like below:

```
for server in ${servTab[*]}; do
echo $server >> df.txt
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh $server df | grep /appl/ | awk '{print \\\$4}' | sed s/%// >> df.txt
expect "password"
send "$pass\r"
expect "$ "
EOF
```

but always file "df.txt" is created in user's home directory no matter of which directory script is. Thanks for help.

Comment: Btw: Add Shebang and `done`.

Comment: Don't use expect for this. If the only reason you're using it is to automate passing a password for ssh, you can use `sshpass`.

Comment: ...and, err, *of course* `df.txt` is created in the current working directory when the redirection creating it is `>> df.txt`. Why would you expect anything different?

Comment: Also, `df | grep | awk | sed` is silly -- `awk` can do everything `grep` or `sed` can.

Comment: And `${servTab[*]}` is a code smell. An unquoted expansion gets string-split and glob-expanded, so if you have `servTab=( "first element" "second element" '*.txt' )`, then `"${servTab[@]}"` has the exact three elements you put in, but `"${servTab[*]}"` is a string that smooshes them all together, and `${servTab[*]}` without the quotes is typically `first`, `element`, `second`, `element`, and then a list of files with the `.txt` extension -- but can potentially be something different, depending on the value of `IFS` and various shell configuration knobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer here is to stop using `expect`; it makes your life more complicated, and in present scenario there's no compelling advantage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make sure this is an array
servTab=( serverOne serverTwo serverThree )

# Advice: Stop passing passwords around and use SSH agent authentication.
[[ $pass ]] || read -s -r -p "Password: " pass

# open your output file *once*; truncate it when that happens.
exec 3>/var/www/html/df.txt

for server in "${servTab[@]}"; do
  echo "$server" >&3
  SSHPASS="$pass" sshpass -e "$server" df      \
    | awk '/appl/ { gsub(/%/, ""); print $4 }' \
    >&3
done
```